# Value from Brown-Forsythe test using R is different to if done manually. Trying to figure out where things went awry

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, t-test, residuals

As the title reads I was working on some exercises and one of the questions asked me to calculate the Brown-Forsythe Test statistic to determine if the variance of the residuals is constant. I've done this procedure in the past manually, but I'm working on expressing things in R code to be able to leverage its power so when the time comes in the future I'll have a handle on things.

So in R I used the `bf.test()` function found in the `onewaytests` package. To perform the test I had to initially split my data in half. The exercise asked me to take the 40 smallest values of `fitted_lm` and make that one group and then the second group was the rest of the values (41 values greater than `fitted_lm`). To make the `bf.test()` work I had to turn my groupings into a factor:

```
> factor_of_fitted = with(data = Commercial_Properties, fitted_lm < median(fitted_lm))
> Commercial_Properties$factor_fitted = factor_of_fitted
```

That's where you see the `factor_fitted` column in my data set.

Once doing such I performed the test and got the following:

```
> bf.test(data = Commercial_Properties, formula = residuals ~ as.factor(factor_fitted), alpha = 0.05)

  Brown-Forsythe Test (alpha = 0.05) 
------------------------------------------------------------- 
  data : residuals and as.factor(factor_fitted) 

  statistic  : 1.421309 
  num df     : 1 
  denom df   : 78.46183 
  p.value    : 0.2367813 

  Result     : Difference is not statistically significant. 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Fortunately I have a solution manual for the textbook I'm using. Looking at the result from the text they have a different value for the test statistic (labeled as $t_{BF}^{*}$)

[image]

So I know if I had done the process manually I would've most likely got the same result as the text. Which in small data sets is feasible, but once I'm dealing with larger data sets it's not going to be as easy to do this manually. So I was wondering what I did wrong in organizing my data to not get the same test statistic as the solution guide?

To be able to make things easier I've included the full data set below:

```
 dput(Commercial_Properties)
structure(list(Rental_Rates = c(13.5, 12, 10.5, 15, 14, 10.5, 
14, 16.5, 17.5, 16.5, 17, 16.5, 16, 16.5, 17.225, 17, 16, 14.625, 
14.5, 14.5, 16.5, 16.5, 15, 15, 13, 12.5, 14, 13.75, 14, 15, 
13.75, 15.625, 15.625, 13, 14, 15.25, 16.25, 13, 14.5, 11.5, 
14.25, 15.5, 12, 14.25, 14, 16.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.75, 16.75, 16.75, 
16.75, 17, 16, 14.5, 15, 15, 16, 15.5, 15.25, 16.5, 19.25, 17.75, 
18.75, 19.25, 14, 14, 18, 13.75, 15, 15.5, 15.9, 15.25, 15.5, 
14.75, 15, 14.5, 13.5, 15, 15.25, 14.5), Age = c(1, 14, 16, 4, 
11, 15, 2, 1, 1, 8, 12, 2, 2, 13, 2, 1, 1, 12, 16, 3, 6, 3, 3, 
3, 14, 1, 15, 16, 2, 16, 2, 3, 3, 16, 16, 13, 1, 14, 3, 15, 1, 
15, 1, 15, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 15, 17, 1, 14, 2, 
1, 0, 18, 16, 13, 20, 18, 16, 1, 2, 16, 1, 15, 4, 20, 3, 3, 18, 
15, 11, 14), Op_Expense_Tax = c(5.02, 8.19, 3, 10.7, 8.97, 9.45, 
8, 6.62, 6.2, 11.78, 14.62, 11.55, 9.63, 12.99, 12.01, 12.01, 
7.99, 10.33, 10.67, 9.45, 12.65, 12.08, 10.52, 9.47, 11.62, 5, 
9.89, 11.13, 7.96, 10.73, 7.95, 9.1, 12.05, 8.43, 10.6, 10.55, 
5.5, 8.53, 9.04, 8.2, 6.13, 8.32, 4, 10.1, 5.25, 11.62, 5.31, 
5.75, 12.46, 12.75, 12.75, 11.38, 5.99, 11.37, 10.38, 10.77, 
11.3, 7.06, 12.1, 10.04, 4.99, 7.33, 12.11, 12.86, 12.7, 11.58, 
11.58, 12.97, 4.82, 9.75, 10.36, 8.13, 13.23, 10.57, 11.22, 10.34, 
10.67, 8.6, 11.97, 11.27, 12.68), Vacancy_Rate = c(0.14, 0.27, 
0, 0.05, 0.07, 0.24, 0.19, 0.6, 0, 0.03, 0.08, 0.03, 0, 0.04, 
0.03, 0, 0.14, 0.12, 0, 0.03, 0.13, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.33, 0.05, 
0.06, 0.22, 0.09, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.1, 0.21, 0.03, 0.04, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.16, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0.57, 0.27, 0, 0.05, 
0, 0.14, 0.05, 0.06, 0.73, 0.22, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0.03, 0.08, 0, 
0.03, 0.02, 0.23, 0.05, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.14, 0.03, 0.03
), Total_Sq_Ft = c(123000, 104079, 39998, 57112, 60000, 101385, 
31300, 248172, 215000, 251015, 291264, 207549, 82000, 359665, 
265500, 299000, 189258, 366013, 349930, 85335, 235932, 130000, 
40500, 40500, 45959, 120000, 81243, 153947, 97321, 276099, 90000, 
184000, 184718, 96000, 106350, 135512, 180000, 315000, 42500, 
30005, 60000, 73521, 50000, 50724, 31750, 168000, 70000, 27000, 
129614, 129614, 130000, 209000, 220000, 60000, 110000, 101206, 
288847, 105000, 276425, 33000, 210000, 240000, 281552, 421000, 
484290, 234493, 230675, 296966, 32000, 38533, 109912, 236000, 
243338, 122183, 128268, 72000, 43404, 59443, 254700, 434746, 
201930), residuals = c(`1` = -1.03567244005944, `2` = -1.51380641405037, 
`3` = -0.591053402133659, `4` = -0.133568082335235, `5` = 0.313283765150399, 
`6` = -3.18718522392237, `7` = -0.538356748944345, `8` = 0.236302385996349, 
`9` = 1.98922037248654, `10` = 0.105829602747806, `11` = 0.0231248303375595, 
`12` = -0.337070751068471, `13` = 0.717869467777838, `14` = -0.39241101481937, 
`15` = -0.20101957286503, `16` = -0.814937024117113, `17` = 0.101690072282649, 
`18` = -1.75913163724428, `19` = -1.2101149159064, `20` = -0.634341765183287, 
`21` = -0.366004170475953, `22` = 0.288596122855648, `23` = -0.0932002476873237, 
`24` = 0.233884283934414, `25` = -0.853339940810852, `26` = -2.12393446949041, 
`27` = 0.466014056944787, `28` = -0.573974675317338, `29` = -1.06882672700907, 
`30` = -0.197717691204396, `31` = -1.12173717691291, `32` = -0.173906919197219, 
`33` = -1.03012563640357, `34` = -0.0909536535687804, `35` = 0.215053952020427, 
`36` = 0.784804746475957, `37` = 1.08392037338663, `38` = -2.13245126940118, 
`39` = -0.185470952077321, `40` = -1.12038545273967, `41` = -0.0127716796287901, 
`42` = 2.50093864322792, `43` = -1.58283345207266, `44` = 0.929599529783516, 
`45` = 0.394236721188825, `46` = 0.117200255343118, `47` = 0.815339786695246, 
`48` = 1.60589656366231, `49` = 0.557941960402757, `50` = 0.494737471820888, 
`51` = 0.207611404280235, `52` = -0.0320457978950357, `53` = 1.15579653742154, 
`54` = 0.234272601000998, `55` = -1.07348973870662, `56` = 1.05964667223628, 
`57` = -0.261711554772372, `58` = 1.03165127260948, `59` = -0.345957206526787, 
`60` = 0.203372872216656, `61` = 0.91796112557882, `62` = 2.9441449324703, 
`63` = 2.45969648166138, `64` = 1.8590887491699, `65` = 1.4518076575634, 
`66` = -0.483857748462958, `67` = -0.756250356020606, `68` = 2.01140230949244, 
`69` = 0.0785504271364723, `70` = 0.00989280872616449, `71` = 1.76689842599545, 
`72` = -0.46393087551268, `73` = -0.510410865690217, `74` = -0.106354745783563, 
`75` = 1.20942716910305, `76` = -0.261085606218594, `77` = -0.627547724654831, 
`78` = 0.910085786900333, `79` = -0.550846871179429, `80` = -2.0301809444414, 
`81` = -0.906819055572569), fitted_lm = c(`1` = 14.5356724400594, 
`2` = 13.5138064140504, `3` = 11.0910534021337, `4` = 15.1335680823352, 
`5` = 13.6867162348496, `6` = 13.6871852239224, `7` = 14.5383567489443, 
`8` = 16.2636976140037, `9` = 15.5107796275135, `10` = 16.3941703972522, 
`11` = 16.9768751696624, `12` = 16.8370707510685, `13` = 15.2821305322222, 
`14` = 16.8924110148194, `15` = 17.426019572865, `16` = 17.8149370241171, 
`17` = 15.8983099277174, `18` = 16.3841316372443, `19` = 15.7101149159064, 
`20` = 15.1343417651833, `21` = 16.866004170476, `22` = 16.2114038771444, 
`23` = 15.0932002476873, `24` = 14.7661157160656, `25` = 13.8533399408109, 
`26` = 14.6239344694904, `27` = 13.5339859430552, `28` = 14.3239746753173, 
`29` = 15.0688267270091, `30` = 15.1977176912044, `31` = 14.8717371769129, 
`32` = 15.7989069191972, `33` = 16.6551256364036, `34` = 13.0909536535688, 
`35` = 13.7849460479796, `36` = 14.465195253524, `37` = 15.1660796266134, 
`38` = 15.1324512694012, `39` = 14.6854709520773, `40` = 12.6203854527397, 
`41` = 14.2627716796288, `42` = 12.9990613567721, `43` = 13.5828334520727, 
`44` = 13.3204004702165, `45` = 13.6057632788112, `46` = 16.3827997446569, 
`47` = 13.6846602133048, `48` = 13.8941034363377, `49` = 16.1920580395972, 
`50` = 16.2552625281791, `51` = 16.5423885957198, `52` = 16.782045797895, 
`53` = 15.8442034625785, `54` = 15.765727398999, `55` = 15.5734897387066, 
`56` = 13.9403533277637, `57` = 15.2617115547724, `58` = 14.9683487273905, 
`59` = 15.8459572065268, `60` = 15.0466271277833, `61` = 15.5820388744212, 
`62` = 16.3058550675297, `63` = 15.2903035183386, `64` = 16.8909112508301, 
`65` = 17.7981923424366, `66` = 14.483857748463, `67` = 14.7562503560206, 
`68` = 15.9885976905076, `69` = 13.6714495728635, `70` = 14.9901071912738, 
`71` = 13.7331015740046, `72` = 16.3639308755127, `73` = 15.7604108656902, 
`74` = 15.6063547457836, `75` = 13.5405728308969, `76` = 15.2610856062186, 
`77` = 15.1275477246548, `78` = 12.5899142130997, `79` = 15.5508468711794, 
`80` = 17.2801809444414, `81` = 15.4068190555726), factor_fitted = c(`1` = TRUE, 
`2` = TRUE, `3` = TRUE, `4` = TRUE, `5` = TRUE, `6` = TRUE, `7` = TRUE, 
`8` = FALSE, `9` = FALSE, `10` = FALSE, `11` = FALSE, `12` = FALSE, 
`13` = FALSE, `14` = FALSE, `15` = FALSE, `16` = FALSE, `17` = FALSE, 
`18` = FALSE, `19` = FALSE, `20` = TRUE, `21` = FALSE, `22` = FALSE, 
`23` = TRUE, `24` = TRUE, `25` = TRUE, `26` = TRUE, `27` = TRUE, 
`28` = TRUE, `29` = TRUE, `30` = FALSE, `31` = TRUE, `32` = FALSE, 
`33` = FALSE, `34` = TRUE, `35` = TRUE, `36` = TRUE, `37` = FALSE, 
`38` = TRUE, `39` = TRUE, `40` = TRUE, `41` = TRUE, `42` = TRUE, 
`43` = TRUE, `44` = TRUE, `45` = TRUE, `46` = FALSE, `47` = TRUE, 
`48` = TRUE, `49` = FALSE, `50` = FALSE, `51` = FALSE, `52` = FALSE, 
`53` = FALSE, `54` = FALSE, `55` = FALSE, `56` = TRUE, `57` = FALSE, 
`58` = TRUE, `59` = FALSE, `60` = TRUE, `61` = FALSE, `62` = FALSE, 
`63` = FALSE, `64` = FALSE, `65` = FALSE, `66` = TRUE, `67` = TRUE, 
`68` = FALSE, `69` = TRUE, `70` = TRUE, `71` = TRUE, `72` = FALSE, 
`73` = FALSE, `74` = FALSE, `75` = TRUE, `76` = FALSE, `77` = TRUE, 
`78` = TRUE, `79` = FALSE, `80` = FALSE, `81` = FALSE), fitted_lm_inter_two = c(`1` = 14.6116798577332, 
`2` = 11.1916330930142, `3` = 10.6929751419447, `4` = 14.9970693316611, 
`5` = 13.5321424338277, `6` = 11.8447040877392, `7` = 14.2387694605939, 
`8` = 17.2471890939162, `9` = 15.4894910008001, `10` = 16.4442024731856, 
`11` = 17.5133080797731, `12` = 16.7244341351021, `13` = 15.1542644276347, 
`14` = 17.0652317677913, `15` = 17.386797838442, `16` = 17.6793446680949, 
`17` = 16.01276803313, `18` = 15.6160310671909, `19` = 15.3871484858081, 
`20` = 15.0355424842674, `21` = 16.9646358788209, `22` = 16.0367231766605, 
`23` = 14.9053935625622, `24` = 14.7219161827122, `25` = 14.8289083816498, 
`26` = 14.5540167514953, `27` = 13.6813659178485, `28` = 14.4313119499636, 
`29` = 14.8848419753938, `30` = 14.5641221825535, `31` = 14.8596894577731, 
`32` = 15.687830923695, `33` = 16.5526108304165, `34` = 12.9785287733056, 
`35` = 14.1202878020442, `36` = 14.1661979578704, `37` = 15.2896847025652, 
`38` = 14.2307529965451, `39` = 14.5936312206155, `40` = 13.203430619155, 
`41` = 14.4301755876548, `42` = 13.3834676419329, `43` = 13.9873375650687, 
`44` = 14.1242292385165, `45` = 13.3240205403671, `46` = 16.2383430173208, 
`47` = 13.8399712533045, `48` = 14.1448935065841, `49` = 16.0967613414401, 
`50` = 16.1584467142199, `51` = 16.2453366247313, `52` = 16.6073805607836, 
`53` = 16.4527862334832, `54` = 15.4786654587565, `55` = 15.4573652950645, 
`56` = 14.2008846171333, `57` = 15.4067278268119, `58` = 14.9712938394994, 
`59` = 15.9119799046393, `60` = 14.8274036384947, `61` = 16.04294294626, 
`62` = 16.8448963733325, `63` = 15.7524858092804, `64` = 17.0106566737114, 
`65` = 17.6513462931722, `66` = 15.0770145346552, `67` = 15.0116830599038, 
`68` = 16.0832647503218, `69` = 14.0206538124515, `70` = 14.8257773376662, 
`71` = 14.1970108477843, `72` = 16.7509472769789, `73` = 16.2216720728956, 
`74` = 15.5064282922696, `75` = 14.5933342257741, `76` = 15.1517080909956, 
`77` = 14.9992784580798, `78` = 12.2017346276572, `79` = 15.0676973219743, 
`80` = 16.924152247941, `81` = 15.9072363357914)), row.names = c(NA, 
-81L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: 1.  t statistics don't have numerator df. It looks like theyre doing an f test.. 2.    Nevertheless, youre right  that they don't correspond

Comment: Is there a "more advanced" Brown-Forsythe that requires different inputs? Sort of like the two ways to calculate the Breusch Pagan test statistic?

Comment: There's a number of slightly different things I've seen called "Brown-Forsythe". You have to look at *exactly* what was implemented, which should be indicated in the help but at worst might come down to reading the code.

Comment: Fair enough...funnily I was just here working away on another exercise and was asking myself "what does the source code exactly do?"....so seems like something I may have to do for a few things.....something to do over time.

Comment: I also have the same confusion. Then I check the paper of onewaytests. It actually tests the equality of means rather than variance. It might explain why you get the different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zihao gong already mentioned [in his comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547343/value-from-brown-forsythe-test-using-r-is-different-to-if-done-manually-trying#comment1129405_547343), the test in the `onewaytests` package is not the right one to perform here.

Instead, you could use `bftest` from the `ALSM` package, which gives you the following result that corresponds to the solution from your textbook:

```r
lm_mod <- lm(residuals ~ factor_fitted, dat)
ALSM::bftest(lm_mod, group = dat$factor_fitted)

#        t.value   P.Value alpha df
# [1,] 0.5520951 0.5824418  0.05 79
```

I used the dataset that you provided at the end of your question as `dat`.

Comment: Forgot about this question, but thanks for the reply. Gives me a reason to go refresh on it.